# Redirect/Alias of URL in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, alias

I have an Apache2.4 server on windows and I have a url like this:
http://example.com/fps/7A/quiz and I wish to redirect it to
http://example.com/fps/7A/quizlet.
I have tried Alias, ScriptAlias and redirect inside the Apache's htaccess file. The alias sometimes caused the whole website and all the pages to break.

Would I have to just make a folder named /quiz/ and put a file that redirects using PHP, or would .htaccess work fine?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
RedirectMatch ^/fps/7A/quiz$ /fps/7A/quizlet
```

Or more general

```
RedirectMatch ^/fps/([^/]+)/quiz$ /fps/$1/quizlet
```

Or even more general

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.*)/quiz$ /$1/quizlet
```

You can add a 301 after `RedirectMatch` to make it a permanent redirect:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/quiz$ /$1/quizlet
```

Comment: I already solved it by making a php redirect. Now I don't really understand how the RedirectMatch works. But next to this, I have another thing I want to do: I want /7A/anythinghere to go to /fps/7A/anythinghere. Wouldn't I have to do something like `RedirectMatch ^/7A/$ /fps/7A/$1?`